# Steps to install Subversion using the CLI on a windows server

Tags: svn

I'm trying to install the SVN (subversion) tool using the command line on a windows VM. In order to automate the installation using ansible, I first need to understand the steps needed to install and Configure the SVN tool and to ensure that the service is running. If I have the underlying steps, I can try and convert them into ansible playbook later.

I came across a chocolatey silent installation that can be invoked using a module win_chocolatey. This will just install the SVN tool but I need to get full list of steps to ensure that the SVN service is running and ready to be used by the apps that push code to SVN repo on this windows VM. So I'm trying to understand what the entire lifecycle of SVN is and how it can be automated via ansible

I've never used SVN before and any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Do you want your VM to act as a repository server or do you just need `svn` installed? Whatever the case, you could start with https://subversion.apache.org/ and move on to https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/